# Small and fast .NET programs? - 65% runtime in ResolvePolicy

Tags: .net, performance, f#, runtime, securitymanager

I tried to build a very very small .NET app in F#.

It just has to convert a small string into another string and print the result to the console like:

convert.exe myString ==> prints something like "myConvertedString"

I used dottrace to analyze the performance:

- 26% (168ms) in my actual string conversion (I thinks this is ok.)
- 65,80% (425ms) in ResolvePolicy in System.Security.SecurityManager

A runtime > 500ms on every execution is way too slow. Can I do something to improve this?

It would be Ok if only the first call needs this time.

Regards, 
  forki

Comment: You could always get a cup of coffee while you wait ;-) Seriously, have you thought about making it a singleton COM service?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do you definitely have to run this as a separate process for each string?

Could you pass in the name of a file containing a lot of strings? That would be significantly more efficient, in terms of:

- Time taken to bring up a process
- Time taken to load all the various bits of .NET
- Time taken to JIT your code
- Time taken to resolve the security policy

Comment: Yeah, whole application overhead is hard here. REALLY hard on micro applications (that incidentally serve hardly a practicap purpose).

Comment: I know. But that's not possible here. The problem is: From time to time there is a single string which needs to be converted.

Comment: @forki23: If it's "from time to time" does it really matter if it takes 500ms or so? What are you calling this from? Could you turn your app into a small server which stays up and responds to TCP requests instead?

Comment: Thinking about the whole process gave me the idea to cache already converted strings in the second tool.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [caspol.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cb6t8dtz.aspx) to turn code access security check off.

Answer (score 1):

you could try to precompile the assembly. with the program ngen it is possible to compile a .net assembly already to machine code, and then to install the assembly in the global assembly path. that should speed up the loading time of the application